# Dynamically fill select options Angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, onchange, ngfor

I'm trying to fill a combo with relevant data from it's parent combo. I'll leave my code below:

**HTML**

```
 <select class="form-control" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option disabled="true">{{ txtOptDefault }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let arrCorp of selCorp" value="{{ arrCorp.corp_id }}">
     <!-- Here I choose 2000. It prints 2000 but nothing happens -->
     {{ arrFiles.corp_id }}. {{ arrCorp.corpname }}</option>
 </select>

 <select class="form-control">
  <option disabled="true">{{ txtOptDefault }}</option>
  <option *ngFor="let arrFiles of selFiles" value="{{ arrFiles.file_id }}">
     {{ arrFiles.file_id }}. {{ arrFiles.filename }}</option>
 </select>
```

**TS**

```
onChange(selection) {
    if (selection === 2000) {
        this.selFiles= [{ 'file_id': id, 'filename': filename },];
    } else {
        this.selFiles = [];
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fill arrFiles depending on the corp selection, which in this case is 2000.

If I add a console.log when selection is 2000 it prints the result correctly, but selFiles doesn't get filled. I guess that ngFor only gets executed when the page loads, how can I make it to work with my code?

Comment: Pleas don’t ask “How to make it work” but something more precise. The préciser it gets, the easier it is for users to help you !

Comment: Sorry, thought the code was enough to understand the question. I've added a little description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use (change) in place of (ngModelChange)

and

```
    onChange(selection) {
    if (selection.target.value === 2000) {
        this.selFiles= [{ 'file_id': id, 'filename': filename },];
    } else {
        this.selFiles = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll be using ngModel later, what makes (change) better for this case?

Comment: Found the solution, had to change === for == since value is a string. It wouldn't have worked without changing ngModelChange to change tho.